# How to set the path for models routes in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a **model file** where I'm exporting the routes

```
const newsRoutes = (app: express.Application): void => {
  app.get('/news', readAll);
  app.get('/news/:id', readOne);
};
```

Then, I'm importing and calling that function passing the instance of the initialized app

```
newsRoutes(app);
```

And I can access it through:

- http://localhost:8080/users
- http://localhost:8080/users/1

I would like to set the path so in the models files I can use `/` instead of `/news` and `/:id` instead of `/news/:id` and also, prepend the `/api` path so the resulting endpoint
would be

- http://localhost:8080/api/users
- http://localhost:8080/api/users/1

I tried with app.use() passing the path and newsRoutes() in the server file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const userRoutes = require('../Routes/UserRoutes');
app.get('User',userRoutes);
```

Similarly, use models and helper files as well